# Python: Why does the id change after copying a list with b = list(a)

Tags: python

Suppose the following code:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = list(a)
print(id(b) == id(a))
```

This yields to:

```
False
```

I would have expected both lists to be of the same id after copying. Why doesn't **b** have the same id as **a**?

Comment: `list(a)` creates a copy. These **are not** the same lists.

Comment: You're copying the entire list, not the reference to it

Comment: In Python all objects have different ids. If they are different objects they have different ids. Simple as that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`list` creates a new copy of the argument. It expects an iterable and consumes all of the iterable's elements into a *new* list.

If you wanted a an additional reference/name that refers to the same list, simply use assignment without the call to `list`.

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = a
print(id(b) == id(a))  # True
```